# mapping json returned from controller to strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Here is my strongly typed view

```
@using ( Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home",null, FormMethod.Post, new { id="FormPost" }))
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name) 
        <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName) 
        <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age)  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Age) 
        <br />

    <input type=submit   value="submit" />
    <br /><br />    
 }
```

This is the view model class:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter first name") ]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I post the form back to the Index action method using the script below

```
ReusableJqueryPost.prototype.CommonPost = function (formId) {

        var fid = $("#" + formId);
        var validated = $(fid).valid();
        if (validated) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(fid).attr('action'),
                data: $(fid).serialize(),
                accept: 'application/json',
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                    alert('error: ' + xhr.responseText + '-' + error);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('DATA SAVED!');
                    var resp = response;    
                }
            });
        }
};
```

The Index Action method can now return as *ActionResult*

```
return View(objMyViewModel);
```

or as or *JsonResult*

```
return Json(objMyViewModel);
```

If I was ***not*** using a jquery post and was returning data as an *ActionResult* then I wouldnt need to do anything on the client side. Asp.net MVC would take care of binding the values to the appropriate text boxes on account of the `@Html.TextBoxFor(....)`

Since I am using a jquery post to post to the action method and returning data as *JsonResult* , I want this same flexibility of auto-binding each element in the json string to the respective `Html.TextBoxFor(...)` textboxes instead of having to use jquery to find the textboxes or selectboxes( if there are any) and then binding the data to it based on the values received in the json string.

**Questions**

1. Is this possible under some feature of asp.net mvc out of the box?
2. Is the only option available there to use jquery to find the textboxes or dropdowns or any other input element by name/id and then assign the value from the json string
3. Is there any way I can write this assignment once so that I can reuse the same code without repeating it all over the project for every view? much like I have one jquery post method here to be used through out the project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps to achieve what you are expecting

1. Make an ajax call to your action
2. Then from action return the partial view as string
3. Then using jquery replace the container with the result

For eg:

Jquery POST :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Controller/Action", // URL
    data: {}, // Your data
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        $("#result").replaceWith(result); // "#result" is your container which you want to replace for eg: div
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```

Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Insert(TypeName model)
    {
        return Json((RenderRazorViewToString("PartialViewName", UpdatedModel)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Rendering View as string:

```
    [NonAction]
    public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out  `@Ajax.BeginForm` - I think it does what you're asking.